# Discord bot that sends a message to channel, when a keyword has been written in twitch chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, twitch-api

I'm looking for discord bot that sends a message to a channel, when a keyword has been written in twitch chat.

example: someone written in chat "hello", then in discord channel I get a message with ping.

Comment: of course im not looking for a particular bot, just a code thank you

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but you won't get free code here. Make some research by yourself, learn actually about how to write a discord bot and come bake if you have some effort done by yourself and we can actually help you

Answer (score 0):

Can just use dyno for this. Autoresponder module

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide something related about your solution